# PatternSyntaxException using apache poi

Tags: java, android, regex, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI in two different projects

The first project is a standalone Java application. Everything is fine here.

The second project is an Android project. I can access the Workbook of an xlsx just fine, but when it comes to evaluating formulas, it crashes with an Exception

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR \P{IsL}
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
   at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction$5.<init>(TextFunction.java:124)
   at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.TextFunction.<clinit>(TextFunction.java:123)
```

This is the code line in question:

```
    final Pattern nonAlphabeticPattern = Pattern.compile("\\P{IsL}");
```

Why does Android not accept this? As I said: It's working fine on a standalone Java application ....

Comment: Use `final Pattern nonAlphabeticPattern = Pattern.compile("\\P{L}");`

Comment: Isn't `\\P{IsL}` a perfectly legal pattern? According to Oracle, it is `Categories may be specified with the optional prefix Is: Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters. Same as scripts and blocks, categories can also be specified by using the keyword general_category (or its short form gc) as in general_category=Lu or gc=Lu.`

Comment: Android is using ICU regex library, Java has its own ICU-based regex. See [*this*](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#gnumber): *Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties are written with the `\p` and `\P` constructs as in Perl. `\p{prop}` matches if the input has the property prop, while `\P{prop}` does not match if the input has that property.*

Comment: Don't get me wrong ... I would change it if I could. It is part of apache poi code from their library

Comment: Do you mean you cannot change the pattern?

Comment: At least I don't know how ... I'd have to recompile the apache poi code, wouldn't I?

Comment: Sorry, can't help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is using ICU regex library that is a bit different from Java regex engine.

See [*this reference*](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#gnumber):

> Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties are written with the `\p` and `\P` constructs as in Perl. `\p{prop}` matches if the input has the property prop, while `\P{prop}` does not match if the input has that property.

Thus, the pattern should be written as

```
Pattern nonAlphabeticPattern = Pattern.compile("\\P{L}");
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it. I recompiled the apache poi sources and replaced the jar for my project. Et voilà

Comment: In POI trunk we now have rewritten the PROPER function to not use regular expressions at all and also fixed a few cases where the method did behave incorrectly, e.g. on some accented characters, see https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/aec95a44918e5331f0d3a746202c713bc8ac6aad